# Creating a Confidence Ellipse in a scatterplot using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

How do I create a confidence ellipse in a scatterplot using matplotlib?

The following code works until creating scatter plot. Then, is anyone familiar with putting confidence ellipses over the scatter plot?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [5,7,11,15,16,17,18]
y = [8, 5, 8, 9, 17, 18, 25]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Following is the reference for Confidence Ellipses from SAS.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/62603/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003160800.htm

The code in sas is like this:

```
proc sgscatter data=sashelp.iris(where=(species="Versicolor"));
  title "Versicolor Length and Width";
  compare y=(sepalwidth petalwidth)
          x=(sepallength petallength)
          / reg ellipse=(type=mean) spacing=4;
run;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [multidimensional confidence intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301071/multidimensional-confidence-intervals)

Comment: @  Saullo Castro have you seen the code in sas and do you think that the method implemented in sas and in the link you provided the same?

Comment: @tester3 - In the example you linked to, the confidence ellipse shown is for the mean, as opposed to for another sample drawn from the same population.  (This is what `type=mean` is specifying.)  My answer that @SaulloCastro linked to shows a confidence ellipse for the entire population (in other words, the area that another sample from the population should fall inside, identical to `type=predicted` in SAS).  Jamie's answer uses this method as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following code draws a one, two, and three standard deviation sized ellipses:

```
x = [5,7,11,15,16,17,18]
y = [8, 5, 8, 9, 17, 18, 25]
cov = np.cov(x, y)
lambda_, v = np.linalg.eig(cov)
lambda_ = np.sqrt(lambda_)
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
for j in xrange(1, 4):
    ell = Ellipse(xy=(np.mean(x), np.mean(y)),
                  width=lambda_[0]*j*2, height=lambda_[1]*j*2,
                  angle=np.rad2deg(np.arccos(v[0, 0])))
    ell.set_facecolor('none')
    ax.add_artist(ell)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Jamie - +1 Shouldn't the ellipses be twice as wide and high, though?  Currently, they're N-sigma wide and high, as opposed to showing the region within N-sigma of the mean.

Comment: @JoeKington Yes, I do think you are absolutely right, matplotlib makes it kind of clear they are the width and height, not the semi-width and semi-height... Have edited the code and image. Thanks!

Comment: Better check @Ben 's answer below, because this code doesn't compute the angle properly. It appeared about 90 degrees flipped in my case.

Comment: Can confirm that this example computes the angle incorrectly; the correct angle is computed as `angle= np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(*v[:,0][::-1]))`

Comment: Yes the proper angle definition should be ```np.degrees(np.arctan2(*v[:,0][::-1]))```

Comment: Shouldn't the width and height be mean_axis + 2 * std_axis? I can assume you subtracted the mean to center data in 0?

Answer (score 29):

After giving the accepted answer a go, I found that it doesn't choose the quadrant correctly when calculating theta, as it relies on [`np.arccos`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arccos.html):

[image: oops]

Taking a look at the ['possible duplicate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301071/multidimensional-confidence-intervals) and [Joe Kington's solution on github](https://github.com/joferkington/oost_paper_code/blob/master/error_ellipse.py), I watered his code down to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

def eigsorted(cov):
    vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
    order = vals.argsort()[::-1]
    return vals[order], vecs[:,order]

x = [5,7,11,15,16,17,18]
y = [25, 18, 17, 9, 8, 5, 8]

nstd = 2
ax = plt.subplot(111)

cov = np.cov(x, y)
vals, vecs = eigsorted(cov)
theta = np.degrees(np.arctan2(*vecs[:,0][::-1]))
w, h = 2 * nstd * np.sqrt(vals)
ell = Ellipse(xy=(np.mean(x), np.mean(y)),
              width=w, height=h,
              angle=theta, color='black')
ell.set_facecolor('none')
ax.add_artist(ell)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: neg slope]

Comment: Does anyone know how to generalise this to 3D (or possibly n dimensions)?

Comment: @Ben Why `w, h = 2 * nstd * np.sqrt(vals)`? That's `4 * np.sqrt(vals)`.

Comment: why it doesn't work when I change plt.scatter(x, y) to plt.scatter(np.mean(x), np.mean(y)). I want the ellipsoid around the mean

Comment: I tried the example and got a blank figure. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @tauran: the radii of the ellipse are sqrt(eigenvalue1) and sqrt(eigenvalue2). vals contains both eigenvalues: [eigenvalue1, eigenvalue2]. When drawing an ellipse you need to specify the width and not the radii of the ellipse: for this 2*sqrt(vals). And now there are many ellipses, but if you want to display the confidence area, such that 95% of the data points are inside that ellipse area, we need to display 2 standard deviations. For this, the multiplication with nstd (=2).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage
&
https://cookierobotics.com/007/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to compute angles explicitly once you have the eigendecomposition of your covariance matrix: the rotation portion already encodes that information for you for free:

```
cov = np.cov(x, y)
val, rot = np.linalg.eig(cov)
val = np.sqrt(val)
center = np.mean([x, y], axis=1)[:, None]

t = np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, 1000)
xy = np.stack((np.cos(t), np.sin(t)), axis=-1)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(*(rot @ (val * xy).T + center))
```

[image]

You can expand your ellipse by applying a scale before translation:

```
plt.plot(*(2 * rot @ (val * xy).T + center))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*In addition to the accepted answer:* I think the correct angle should be:

```
angle=np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(*v[:,np.argmax(abs(lambda_))][::-1])))
```

and the corresponding width (larger eigenvalue) and height should be:

```
width=lambda_[np.argmax(abs(lambda_))]*j*2, height=lambda_[1-np.argmax(abs(lambda_))]*j*2
```

As we need to find the corresponding eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue. Since "the eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered" according to the specs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html and `v[:,i]` is the eigenvector corresponding to the `eigenvalue lambda_[i]`; we should find the correct column of the eigenvector by `np.argmax(abs(lambda_))`.

Answer (score 0):

We draw a confidence ellipse by calling the following function that calculates its x and y coordinates:

```
import numpy as np
def get_ellipse(center: np.ndarray, cova: np.ndarray, nsigma: int = 1, npoints: int = 1000) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Return the coordinates of a covariance ellipse.

    Args:
        center (np.ndarray): The center of the ellipse.
        cova (np.ndarray): The covariance matrix.
        nsigma (int, optional): The number of standard deviations for the ellipse. Defaults to 1.
        npoints (int, optional): The number of points to generate on the ellipse. Defaults to 1000.

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: The coordinates of the ellipse.
    """
    cholesky_l = np.linalg.cholesky(cova)
    t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, npoints)
    circle = np.column_stack([np.cos(t), np.sin(t)])
    ellipse = nsigma * circle @ cholesky_l.T + center
    return ellipse.T
```

The function, proposed by one of my teaching assistants, uses the Cholesky decomposition. The confidence ellipses can be plotted with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [5,7,11,15,16,17,18]
y = [8, 5, 8, 9, 17, 18, 25]
mean = np.mean([x, y])
cov = np.cov(x, y, ddof=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")

ax.scatter(x,y)

x_1sigma, y_1sigma = get_ellipse(mean, cov, nsigma=1)
ax.plot(x_1sigma, y_1sigma, label='$1\sigma$')
x_2sigma, y_2sigma = get_ellipse(mean, cov, nsigma=2)
ax.plot(x_2sigma, y_2sigma, label='$2\sigma$')
x_3sigma, y_3sigma = get_ellipse(mean, cov, nsigma=3)
ax.plot(x_3sigma, y_3sigma, label='$3\sigma$')

ax.legend()
```

We prefer using ddof=1 in numpy.cov to get an unbiased estimator of the covariance matrix.

[Plot of the 1, 2, and 3σ covariance ellipses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuapH.png)