# Looking for a detailed method to plot contours of confidence level

Tags: statistics, contour, confidence-interval, standard-deviation

I try to find out a method or a tutorial to know how are plotted the contours of different confidence levels (68%, 95%, 99.7% etc ...).

Here below an example of these contours on a plot that I would like to generate:

[image: Cosmology - Omega_Lambda versus Omega_matter]

It represents the constraints on cosmological parameters (\omega_Lambda represents dark energy and \Omega_m total matter quantity).

Once I have data sets on \Omega_Lambda and \Omega_mat, how can I produce these contours : I know what is a confidence level but I only know the standard deviation.

If I plot standard deviation for both parameters from the expected values, I get a cross symbol on it (horizontally for \Omega_m and vertically for \Omega_Lambda) : but from this cross, how to draw contours at different confidence levels?

On the figure above, these contours look like a 2D parametric curve where I have points (Omega_Lambda(t), Omega_m(t)) with t parameter but I don't think  they are drawn like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [Matplotlib's contour plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html): the `levels` parameter seems to be what you need.

The plots in your example are not obtained from raw data, but from a statistical model of raw data. So you could first fit multivariate normal distributions to your data using [numpy.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [numpy.cov](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html), then generate the multivariate normal pdf values with [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal). You can also find a code snippet doing confidence ellipses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126061/creating-a-confidence-ellipses-in-a-sccatterplot-using-matplotlib#20127387) (which seems to be exactly the kind of thing you were looking for).

Comment: -@Stefano Gogioso : thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it seems this is not about confidence levels as we use it in statistics domain.

Comment: @youpilat13: Sorry, I thought you already had a statistical model fitted. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: -@ Stefano Gogioso : thanks, that's what I was looking for. Regards