# Simple ellipse on chart (pyplot, k-means Coursera course)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently doing one of my 1st Coursera courses on Data Science (K-Means). I'm doing fine with almost everything but got stuck on a simple task. Plotting two ellipses on my "clusters" to highlight the distance of the "centroids" to it's STDs.

Must be something foolish but I browsed Google and the course itself and got no luck.

The code (pretty amateur I know) and plot it generates are bellow.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title('Cluster Segregtion')
plt.scatter(c0['V1n'], c0['V2n'], color = 'blue', s = 30 , alpha = 0.5)
plt.scatter(c1['V1n'], c1['V2n'], color = 'red', s = 30 , alpha = 0.5)
plt.scatter(clusters[:,0], clusters[:,1], color = 'orange', s = 40000, alpha = 0.3)
```

[image: Where you see circles should be ellipses]

Can someone give me a hand with a simple ellipse code?

Best regards
FC

Comment: [Creating a Confidence Ellipses in a sccatterplot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126061/creating-a-confidence-ellipses-in-a-sccatterplot-using-matplotlib) and [Plot a confidence ellipse](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the patch module of matplotlib. For example (with some made up numbers):

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.scatter([2,4,6,3,4,5,4,], [1,8,9,3,9,7,2,]) 
patch = Ellipse((4,5), width=9, height=3, angle=75, alpha=0.4, ls='solid', ec='g', fc = 'r', lw='2.')
ax.add_patch(patch)
```

You may want to find the coordinates and angle from the data itself, though, but this is a separate question. You can read matplotlib documentation about patches.

Comment: Perfect! Thank's a lot!