# Matplotlib patch not getting applied properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

[image]

I expected something like above to be applied to my scatter plot.but instead i received this

[image]

code is as below

```
# Data
import matplotlib.patches as patches
df1=pd.DataFrame({'x_pos': x, 'y_pos': y })
print(df1)

 
# Plot
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot( 'x_pos', 'y_pos', data=df1, linestyle='none', marker='o')

 
# Annotation
ax1.add_patch(
patches.Circle(
(35, 40),          
3,                
alpha=0.3, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black", linewidth=1, linestyle='solid'
)
)

# Show the graph
plt.show()
```

Dataframe

```
   x_pos  y_pos
0       38  62506
3       33  64991
4       32  50825
5       44  57568
7       38  59365
..     ...    ...
301     44  55140
302     38  58062
303     48  59728
307     39  48513
310     43  45046
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You are creating a circle with center `(35, 40)`, while the data points are far away, having x-values around 40 and y-values around 60,000. Also note that when there is a large difference in aspect ratio between the x and y direction, the circle will be squeezed to a thin ellipse.

Comment: how can i fix the issue ? @JohanC

Comment: Maybe use another  center? Maybe draw an ellipse with a larger y radius? What do you want to show?

Comment: i want to highlight the middle section of the graph with a patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mean of the x and the y positions as the center for an [ellipse](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html).  And the standard deviation in x and in y for its radius in both directions. Note that for an ellipse, the parameters are the width and height, so the double of the radius.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x_pos': np.random.randint(32, 49, 100),
                    'y_pos': np.random.randint(45000, 63000, 100)})
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot('x_pos', 'y_pos', data=df1, linestyle='none', marker='o')

ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Ellipse(
        (df1['x_pos'].mean(), df1['y_pos'].mean()),
        df1['x_pos'].std() * 2, df1['y_pos'].std() * 2,
        alpha=0.3, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black", linewidth=1, linestyle='solid'))

plt.show()
```

[image: adding an ellipse near the center of a set of points]

See also [this tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126061/creating-a-confidence-ellipses-in-a-sccatterplot-using-matplotlib) about drawing a confidence ellipse.

Here is how the code could look like to draw confidence ellipses for 1,2 and 3 standard deviations (using rotated data to test the ellipse rotation):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(32, 49, 100)
y = np.random.randint(45000, 50000, 100) + x * 500
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x_pos': x, 'y_pos': y})

lamda, v = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(df1['x_pos'], df1['y_pos']))
lamda = np.sqrt(lamda)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot('x_pos', 'y_pos', data=df1, linestyle='none', marker='o')

for num_std in range(1, 4):
    ax1.add_patch(
        patches.Ellipse(
            xy=(df1['x_pos'].mean(), df1['y_pos'].mean()),
            angle=np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(*v[:, 0][::-1])),
            width=lamda[0] * num_std * 2, height=lamda[1] * num_std * 2,
            alpha=0.1, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black", linewidth=1, linestyle='solid'))
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing confidence ellipses]